# questions about if,what does 'if +some variable:'(without any condition) mean?

Tags: python

```
def string_to_int_list(s):
  L1=[]
  for i in s.split(','):
     if i:#what does this line mean?
       L1.append(int(i))
     return L1
```

I want to convert string to list,and if I delete 'if i',it will remind me that ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: It's absurd to add a `return` inside a loop.

Comment: Every expression is a [condition](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#booleans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `i` has a value, the condition will return `true`, if the value of `i` is `None` (empty), it will return `false`. It's the same as `i != None`.

Also I test that if the split function returns an empty string `""` it will not pass the if condition.

For check if a string is numeric (0 - 9) you can use `str.isdigit()`

> **str.isdigit()**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

This code works:

```
def string_to_int_list(s):
  L1=[]
  for i in s.split(','):
     if i and i.isdigit():#what does this line mean?
       L1.append(int(i))
  return L1
     
a = "1,2,3,q,43,hello"

b = string_to_int_list(a)
print b
```

It will return `[1, 2, 3, 43]`

Note that I remove indentation to `return` because it has no sense inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is splitting your string by `,` and then converting to integer if you see a valid value.

Let's say your `1,2,3,4,,,5`

What the script is returning you a list of `[1,2,3,4,5]`

You should try what if condition returns for a empty string, None, empty list i.e. [] or {}.

This script will fail if you have "abc,2,3,4,5"

You can also functional loops like

```
filter(lambda x : x , map(lambda x : int(x) if x else None, a.split(",")))
```